# link_to _remove is working but link_to_add is not working in nested_form RAILS 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-form-for

I followed https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

the remove function is working but the add field is not working.

In my model i properly accepted nested attributes. I have division that has many departments.

**In division.rb**

```
class Division < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :departments_attributes
  has_many :departments, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :departments, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

**In department.rb**

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :division_id, :name
  belongs_to :division
  belongs_to :user
end
```

department belongs to division which is right.

In my divisions_controller.rb

my new method works exactly as Ryan B's example: https://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples/tree/nested_form

```
def new
    @division = Division.new
    @division.departments.build
  end
```

Plus I require nested_form.js inside my application.js

```
//= require nested_form
```

nested_form.js:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('form a.add_nested_fields').live('click', function() {
    // Setup
    var assoc   = $(this).attr('data-association');            // Name of child
    var content = $('#' + assoc + '_fields_blueprint').html(); // Fields template

    // Make the context correct by replacing new_<parents> with the generated ID
    // of each of the parent objects
    var context = ($(this).closest('.fields').find('input:first').attr('name') || '').replace(new RegExp('\[[a-z]+\]$'), '');

    // context will be something like this for a brand new form:
    // project[tasks_attributes][new_1255929127459][assignments_attributes][new_1255929128105]
    // or for an edit form:
    // project[tasks_attributes][0][assignments_attributes][1]
    if(context) {
      var parent_names = context.match(/[a-z_]+_attributes/g) || [];
      var parent_ids   = context.match(/(new_)?[0-9]+/g) || [];

      for(i = 0; i < parent_names.length; i++) {
        if(parent_ids[i]) {
          content = content.replace(
            new RegExp('(_' + parent_names[i] + ')_.+?_', 'g'),
            '$1_' + parent_ids[i] + '_');

          content = content.replace(
            new RegExp('(\\[' + parent_names[i] + '\\])\\[.+?\\]', 'g'),
            '$1[' + parent_ids[i] + ']');
        }
      }
    }

    // Make a unique ID for the new child
    var regexp  = new RegExp('new_' + assoc, 'g');
    var new_id  = new Date().getTime();
    content     = content.replace(regexp, "new_" + new_id);

    $(this).before(content);
    $(this).closest("form").trigger('nested:fieldAdded');
    return false;
  });

  $('form a.remove_nested_fields').live('click', function() {
    var hidden_field = $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]')[0];
    if(hidden_field) {
      hidden_field.value = '1';
    }
    $(this).closest('.fields').hide();
    $(this).closest("form").trigger('nested:fieldRemoved');
    return false;
  });
});
```

I didn't change something in the nested_form.js because I copied it from the complex sample repo, so that is the default.

Any workaround would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry...

I solved my queries using COCOON gem. https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

It's pretty easy to use.